Apache redirect infinite loop
I want to have a redirect from
https://example.com/app/my.page
to
https://example.com/app/my.page?login=INTERNAL
but unfortunately I go into an infinite loop
I have some staging script for httpd.conf configuration, so the syntax for the config is not the standard one, but I can show you this:
pattern="^(/app/my.page)"
substitution="$1?login=INTERNAL" 
flags="[R=302]"


Please try this solution in order to perform the redirect and avoid inifinite loops.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/my.page$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !login=INTERNAL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/my.page?login=INTERNAL [L,R=302]
